# Redis Pub Sub - Only one subscriber to Act on expired event

Tags: redis

I'm implementing redis Keyspace notifications in my application which is having 10 instances on our production environment.

My pubsub listens for expired event in map1 and decrements in map2 based on that.

This works fine on my local machine. My issue is that when I deploy my application with multiple instances , I think all instances will read expired event and all will decrement the key whereas I want to restrict that only 1 instance should decrement.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your listeners will have to coordinate the decrement somehow. You can do that with some sort of locking, but a simpler way perhaps would be embed a notion of version/timestamp into this logic. Here's what I had in mind.

What if you include a timestamp in your "map2"? An expired event has it's own timestamp, so you can have the listeners check-and-set against that (tip: I'd use Lua for the CAS). This will prevent race-like conditions and multiple decrements in one go.

Note: Redis PubSub is amazing, but note that your current solution does not ensure the decrement in "map2" in case a message is lost. In the very near future, Redis will offer the Stream data type, that is much more suitable for that type of job. Specifically, the Stream Consumer Groups functionality is IMO just what you need here for replacing keyspace notifications.